# Receiving two natural numbers and calculating how many times one of them appears in the other. java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that receives from the user two numbers. one (x) is a number between 0 - 9 and the second (y) is any natural number. the problem is that I want to check how many times x is in y for example: if x = 2 and y = 2245 then the output would be 2

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 3;
int y = 233457693;

int total = 0;
String[] ys = String.valueOf(y).split("");
for (String s : ys) {
    if (s.equals(String.valueOf(x))) total++;
}
System.out.println(total);
```

prints 3

Answer (score 0):

My trick is to transform **int** in **String**, after find with **Matcher** class and count how many **String** x are in the **String** y.

So, I try something like that and it's worked:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 2245;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(x + ""); //Create the pattern with the x number
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(y + ""); //Create the matcher wtih de pattern and insert y in string

int c = 0; 
while (matcher.find()) c++; //Count the matches

System.out.println(c); //Print
```

Ouput:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for Java 8 and higher using Stream:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 2245;
long count = String.valueOf(y).chars().filter(ch -> ch == Character.forDigit(x,10)).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert x and y to String and use charAt() method.

```
    int x = 2;
    int y = 2245;
    int counter = 0;

    String xString = String.valueOf(x);
    String yString = String.valueOf(y);


    for(int i=0; i<yString.length(); i++)
    {
        if(yString.charAt(i)==xString.charAt(0))
            counter++;
    }

    System.out.println(counter);
```